# Enterprise built .wsp deployable to Standard Edition?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, solution-package, solution-deployment

Is it possible to build/package a .wsp on a machine with Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise Edition (DEV machine) and deploy it to a machine with Sharepoint 2010 Standard Edition (PROD machine) installed?

Comment: It'll depend on what the wsp is doing, clarify it and we can give you a better answer. Ideally dev and prod will be on the same version and update level.

Comment: What features does the WSP rely on? It also depends on things like what 'types' (like column types) are used.

Comment: I agree it really depends what wsp is actually doing? + are there existing wsps being deployed this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSP package will not change depending on which edition of SharePoint is installed on the Development machine. So if you take the same visual studio project and package it on a machine with Foundation, Standard or Enterprise the WSP will be identical.

BUT by developing (and testing) on a machine which has a more advanced edition than the PROD farm you run the risk of not catching that you include dependencies on that advanced edition into your development.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I meant. With "built" I meant the compiled and packaged .wsp file, not "developing". Your second point is absolutly right. If I include features of enterprise edition in my code and deploy it to a standard edition server, those things will not work.